# Testng - ExcelDataProvider - Rows is not recognized from excel sheet

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, testng

I have a class "Application", which has array variable let's say document[] documents.
Also, I have created two others class "User" and "Sales" with its own set of variables.

Now on my excel work book, I have three sheets Application, User and Sales.

On the selenium automation code, after reading the user data when i try to read Sales data, it says  sales data is not recognized (on the excel sheet sale1 is not recognized).

Please help.

**Application Class**
**ID        Application1    documents**
E42421  Applicant1      user1,sale1

**User Class**
**key       first   last**
user1   sara    kin

**Sales Class**
**key       business    sales**
sale1   steel       20000

Answer (score 0):

```
As far as I got ur question, its regarding reading the data from each sheet in an existing excel sheet, try the below one, you can read the while data in a 2 D array:

Workbook book = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(fileNameWithLocation));
        Sheet sheet = book.getSheet(0); //or book.getSheet(sheetName);

        //CellFinder cellFind = new CellFinder(sheet);
        String [][]testDataProvider = new String[sheet.getRows()][sheet.getColumns()];
        for(int row=0;row<sheet.getRows();row++)
        {
            //c=0 is fileLocation passed in method FetchDataFromExcelSheet, so counting from c=1
            for (int col = 0; col < sheet.getColumns(); col++)
            {
                String data = sheet.getCell(col, row).getContents().toString();
                testDataProvider[row][col] = data;      
            }
        }
        book.close();
        return testDataProvider;
```